# responding error in c# with asp.net

Tags: web-services

i m developing my college last year project.there include web sms service ..i have also demo of this web service .that is in runnable condition .but when that web service demo is execute it gives me a some code like that->>>100=cd859c0c-f652-4612-92f7-cccdd50331680, .

it doesn't affect me but it redirect that web service page from my website.

and still when i include that web service in my project it nothing give me Any response.-->>> string msg = "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii";
                            string str = "http://mobi1.blogdns.com/apisms/SMSSenders.aspx?UserID=KSMSCIT&UserPass=123456&Message=" + msg + "&MobileNo=" + lblsmob + "&GSMID=" + "password";
                            //Response.Redirect(str);
                            HttpWebRequest httpreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);
                            HttpWebResponse httpres = (HttpWebResponse)httpreq.GetResponse();
                            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(httpres.GetResponseStream());
                            string results = sr.ReadLine();

```
                        Label2.Text = results;
                        sr.Close();
```

shows that web service included in my project ...

so give me response....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jWkm.png)